# nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "COMMENT" not found; SQL statement:

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

Running spring boot test case for JPA repository with H2 database.

In data.sql file for H2 database I have tried with column name as "COMMENT" and also with COMMENT still getting the same exception. My repository extends PagingAndSortingRepository.

Exception

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "COMMENT" not found; SQL statement:INSERT INTO RESEARCH_REQUEST (ID, MOD_COUNT, CLIENT_NAME, "COMMENT", PROCESS_ID, INITIATED_BY, INITIATED_AT, STATUS_CD, CREATOR, CREATE_TS) VALUES (500,0, 'Test Client','Test comment', 987654, 'test6@test.com', TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-12-19 12:03:21.000000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'), 'A', 'test6@test.com', TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-12-19 12:03:21.000000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')) [42122-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.table.Table.getColumn(Table.java:682)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumn(Parser.java:936)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnList(Parser.java:920)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsertGivenTable(Parser.java:1258)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1222)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:431)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:335)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:307)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:278)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:611)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:549)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1247)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:217)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:205)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:473)
```

data.sql

```
INSERT INTO RESEARCH_REQUEST (ID, MOD_COUNT, CLIENT_NAME, "COMMENT", PROCESS_ID, INITIATED_BY, INITIATED_AT, STATUS_CD, CREATOR, CREATE_TS) VALUES (500,0, 'Test Client','Test comment', 987654, 'test6@test.com', TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-12-19 12:03:21.000000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'), 'A', 'test6@test.com', TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-12-19 12:03:21.000000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));
```

Entity class

```
@Column(name = "[COMMENT]", length = 1000)
private String comment;
```

main application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xx.xx.com:xxxx:xxxxx
spring.datasource.driverClassName= oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.type= com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.maximumPoolSize=2
spring.datasource.maxLifeTime=300000
spring.datasource.minimumIdle=1
spring.datasource.idleTimeout=300000
spring.datasource.connectionTimeout=10000
spring.datasource.poolName=xxx-pool
```

test application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:h2:mem:test;Mode=Oracle;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driverClassName= org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.type= com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.datasource.initializationFailTimeout=1000
spring.datasource.connectionTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.maximumPoolSize=1
spring.datasource.maxLifetime=300000
spring.datasource.poolName=xxx-pool
```

Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes =XXXMicroserviceLauncher.class)
public class ResearchRequestRepositoryTest {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Column(name = "[COMMENT]", length = 1000)
private String comment;
```

In your code you are providing @column annotation with name and in name you don't need to use [].

Try this:

```
@Column(name = "COMMENT", length = 1000)
```

private String comment;

also check your field name in database table and provide the same in query.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, tried with above approach, the test cases passed and application started up fine, however when I tested the application (which tries to insert a row in oracle table) it is not able to insert record in oracle table.

Comment: The code mentioned in question is only to create a new column in db.
may be you doing something wrong in your  code to save the data.

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you,please accept the answer and up vote it.
Thanks